# Suppress vertical space at beginning of macro when there is no preceding paragraph

Tags: beamer, macros, itemize, paragraphs, vertical-spacing

I want to create a variant of the `itemize` command for Beamer that spreads the items vertically. This should increase the space between items as well as to preceding text.

With other words, I want a command that obviates the need for any vertical spacing command in examples like the following:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme[height=10mm]{Rochester}

\newcommand{\items}{
    \item dolor
    \item sit
    \item amet
    \item consectetur
    \item adipiscing
    \item elit
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Lorem Ipsum}
        \begin{itemize}
            \setlength{\itemsep}{\fill}
            \items
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
    
    \begin{frame}{Lorem}
        Ipsum:
        \vfill
        \begin{itemize}
            \setlength{\itemsep}{\fill}
            \items
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

For illustration, this produces:

[image: output: first frame]
[image: output: second frame]

Now, I got as far as:

```
\newenvironment{itemise}[1][\fill]
{\vspace{#1}\begin{itemize}\setlength{\itemsep}{#1}}
{\end{itemize}}
```

With this, I can reduce the document body of the above to:

```
\begin{frame}{Lorem Ipsum}
    \vspace{-\fill}
    \begin{itemise}
        \items
    \end{itemise}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Lorem}
    Ipsum:
    \begin{itemise}
        \items
    \end{itemise}
\end{frame}
```

However, I still have a `\vspace{-\fill}` in the second line necessary to negate the initial space added by environment which is spurious because there is no preceding text.

How can I make my command more intelligent such that it doesn’t add a space when there is no preceding paragraph? (Bonus points for solutions that also work with succeeding paragraphs.)

Comment: Should only the items be spread out or can all paragraphs be distributed over the frame? (I'm wondering if a simple `\usepackage{parskip}
\setlength{\parskip}{\fill}` with the normal itemize would do the job ...)

Comment: @samcarter: You hardly ever have paragraphs following each other, but I wouldn’t mind them being spread. Your suggestion produces a slightly larger spacing, which is okay in all the examples I quickly tested, but not completely satisfying. Moreover, I can only select `\fill` (or any other given space) as the space, instead of making this an option to `itemise`.